# Cannot install devtools package on mac

Tags: r, package, installation, devtools, ggbiplot

I would like to use the ggbiplot function in R. I tried to install the devtools package first, but it doesn´t work.

I am using R studio Version 1.2.1335 and have a mac with version 10.14.5

Tried different types of code

install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
library(ggbiplot)

or

library(devtools)
install_github("ggbiplot", "vqv")

and i tried to answer this questiion Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?
y/n: with y and n

> install.packages("devtools")
>   also installing the dependencies ‘fs’, ‘usethis’, ‘testthat’

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
fs        1.2.7  1.3.1              TRUE
usethis   1.4.0  1.5.1             FALSE
testthat  2.0.1  2.2.1              TRUE
devtools 1.13.6  2.1.0             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?
y/n: n
versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/fs_1.2.7.tgz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 746131 bytes (728 KB)

downloaded 728 KB

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/testthat_2.0.1.tgz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1660043 bytes (1.6 MB)

downloaded 1.6 MB

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/c0/sg0bg4dx2vz4qw6zdqgc4fpr0000gn/T//RtmpaTVVAF/downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘usethis’, ‘devtools’

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_1.5.1.tar.gz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 620225 bytes (605 KB)

downloaded 605 KB

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.1.0.tar.gz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 378899 bytes (370 KB)

downloaded 370 KB

- installing *source* package ‘usethis’ ...
  ** Paket ‘usethis’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘fs’ 1.2.7 is being loaded, but >= 1.3.0 is required
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘usethis’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/usethis’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘usethis’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/devtools’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/c0/sg0bg4dx2vz4qw6zdqgc4fpr0000gn/T/RtmpaTVVAF/downloaded_packages’

> library(devtools)
>   there is no package called ‘devtools’

Comment: Try first with `install.packages("usethis")`

Comment: Do you have Xcode and the command-line tools installed?

Comment: Did you resolve this? Answer below does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (macOS Catalina 10.15.3, R version 3.6.2) and solved it by first installing 'openssl@1.1'

If you have homebrew you can install this via the command line
'brew install openssl@1.1'

(you also need Xcode and command line tools installed!)